# Textures show in material view, but are magenta in rendered view (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, texture-baking

I've been working on a scene with some subsurface scattering materials, and to save time and reduce grain in the render, I've baked those materials to textures (in OpenEXR format). However, after closing and reloading the blend file, some of the textures now appear as magenta in rendered view, as if they couldn't be loaded, even though they show up correctly mapped in material view. All of the objects are UV mapped, those UV maps are enabled (as far as I can tell), and the texture runs to the material output via an emission shader.

Here's what it looks like in material view:
[image]

Here's what it looks like in rendered view:
[image]

And here's what the material setup looks like for all 3 materials:
[image]

Interestingly, one of the textures appears in rendered view fine, but the others don't, although I set them up through the same process. Whether the textures are loaded from a folder or packed into the blend file doesn't appear to have any difference on the result.

Comment: Does CPU/GPU make a difference? [GPUs can only support about 5 exr images at once atm](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/31072/599)

Comment: @gandalf3 Yes, it does. I had more than 5 floating point textures in the scene, and wasn't aware of the limitation. It looks like that was my problem.